# How to install a "new" command into bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

Here is a Linux distro (Solus) in which bash is not quite complete. 
It seems that command `adduser` is missing. 
Command `adduser` is not the same command as `useradd`.

In Ubuntu both commands are built-in in bash. 
How do I install the command `adduser` into bash (of Solus)?

Comment: As [ivanivan says](https://superuser.com/q/1211452/354511#1211454), commands (with a few exceptions — see [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)) are not built in to bash.  Think of the grocery store and the library; and now think of your car.  You can *get to* the grocery store and the library in your car, but they’re not built in to your car.  Same thing with bash and programs/scripts like ``adduser`` and ``useradd``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not built in to bash.  Bash is its own.  In Debian (and therefore Ubuntu), `adduser` is part of the "adduser" package – as is `deluser` (and both are just shell scripts), but the `useradd` and `userdel` programs come from the `passwd` package.

Since Solus is a from-ground-up distribution and not based on an existing one, you'll need to use their method of adding/removing users. 
See [Managing Users](https://solus-project.com/articles/configuration/managing-users/en/) at the Solus Help Center.